# floor a Series to a given array

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, series, floor

How can I efficiently floor a pandas Series (or an Index level) to a given array (Series, Index), i.e. map every element `x` in the Series to the maximum element `y` in the floor array such that `y <= x`?

Here is an example:

```py
import pandas as pd

# the series
x = pd.Series([1.0, 1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5, 6.6, 7.7, 8.8, 9.9, 10.1, 11.11])

# the floor array
y = pd.Series([1.0, 4.0, 10.0])

# expected result (can be a numpy array, a Series, a list, etc...)
z = [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 10.0, 10.0]
```

You can assume that both the series and the array are sorted in the ascending order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [`pd.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25/reference/api/pandas.cut.html):

```
pd.cut(x, bins=list(y)+[np.inf], right=False, labels=y).astype(float)
```

Output:

```
0      1.0
1      1.0
2      1.0
3      1.0
4      4.0
5      4.0
6      4.0
7      4.0
8      4.0
9      4.0
10    10.0
11    10.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: can you explain it?

Comment: @ArcoBast you can read through the linked doc. It's exactly what `pd.cut` is for.